# Uniform order-based crossover implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to implement Uniform order based crossover, which should be using shuffle logic, like:

Initial:

```
a =[5, 1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3]
b =[6, 7, 5, 2, 8, 3, 4, 1]
```

Randomly select positions that will no longer change. The remaining
positions are filled with the missing elements copied in the order they
appear in the other parent

```
a' =[ , 7,  , 2, 8,  , , 1]
b' =[ , 1,  , 6, 7,  , , 3]
```

Starting from the second crossover site the values that are not already
present in the offspring from the alternative parent (the parent other than
the one whose values are copied by the offspring in the initial phase) in the
order they appear
output:

```
a = [5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6, 3, 1]
b = [5, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3]
```

I have tried to implement this but my code is not able to hold fixed index.

cross.py

```
import random
def uniformCrossover(indA, indB):
    """
    Your Uniform Crossover Implementation
    """
    crossprob = 0.1
    size = min(len(indA), len(indB))
    for i in range(size):
        if random.random() < crossprob:
            indA[i], indB[i] = indB[i], indA[i]
        return indA, indB

a,b = uniformCrossover([5, 1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3], [6, 7, 5, 2, 8, 3, 4, 1])
```

Comment: Well, all you do so far is, to swap elements when the random number is lower than `crossprob`. So it can happen, that you have values twice per array.

Comment: Also you return after the first iteration in your loop, as the `return` statement is intended (most propably not wanted).